# How we can put label on custom pin in MapKit?

Tags: iphone, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I want to display a dynamic label on custom pin.
I used MKMapView, CLLocationManager,MKAnnotationView and MKPinAnnotationView.
So, please help me friends.

Like:

[image]

Comment: you mean when user tap on pin they see the name or other text on particular pin right...?

Comment: you can use annotation by setting its name and discription and image in mapkit.

Comment: No.. When map load there is some default pin and it show label on that pin without tap. [Just like :](http://www.ereachconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/map-with-pin.jpg)

Comment: then you can use overlay for that purpose.

Comment: Ok.. Thank for reply.. There is any online tutorial or documents which i can refer.. Pls suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you want the pin to have a letter on it then you need to set the image of the annotation view in `viewForAnnotation`. If you're planning to change the pin for each annotation you'll need to create the image dynamically. They will be plenty of code around this but it comes down to this

```
annotationView.image = anImage;
```

Comment: please explain how i add image and also label in map pin.

Comment: There are lots of resources to explain how to do those things. If you've tried one and it doesn't work, ask a new question stating what you did and what happens/doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

First create a custom `MKAnnotationView` based class:

**Swift 3**

```
  class CustomAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {  
    var label: UILabel?

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
  }
```

Then make sure your ViewController class adds `NKMapViewDelegate` as a delegate:

**Swift 3**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
  }
}
```

Then add the following method to your `ViewController` which will be called by the MapView whenever an annotation is added to the map:

**Swift 3**

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationIdentifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"
    guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
      return nil
    }

    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    if annotationView == nil {
      annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
      if case let annotationView as CustomAnnotationView = annotationView {
        annotationView.isEnabled = true
        annotationView.canShowCallout = false
        annotationView.label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -5.5, y: 11.0, width: 22.0, height: 16.5))
        if let label = annotationView.label {
          label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16.0)
          label.textAlignment = .center
          label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
          label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
          annotationView.addSubview(label)
        }
      }
    }

    if case let annotationView as CustomAnnotationView = annotationView {
      annotationView.annotation = annotation
      annotationView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "YourPinImage")
      if let title = annotation.title,
        let label = annotationView.label {
        label.text = title
      }
    }

    return annotationView
  }
```

Once you've done all this, the annotation can be added like this:

**Swift 3**

```
  let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
  annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: /* latitude */, longitude: /* longitude */)
  annotation.title = "Your Pin Title"
  mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```